# Difference Between Prepare For Segue And Prepare for Unwind - Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

What are the differences between prepare for segue and prepare for unwind? I have implemented both of these into Xcode project and they both come out with the same result. The code that I have implemented both of these functions are: ***(with prepare for unwind)***

```
override func prepare(for unwind: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let variableUnwind = ("StackOverFlow")

    if unwind.identifier == "toFirstViewController"  {

        let hello = unwind.destination as! ViewController

        hello.username = textField.text!

        print(hello.username)



    }

}
```

and:***(with prepare for unwind)***

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let variableUnwind = ("StackOverFlow")

        if segue.identifier == "toFirstViewController"  {

            let hello = segue.destination as! ViewController

            hello.username = textField.text!

            print(hello.username)



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both the same method.  It doesn't matter whether the parameter name is `unwind` or `segue`, the selector is `prepare(for:sender:)`.

If you try implementing both of them in the same class, you will get the error: **invalid redeclaration of 'prepare(for:sender:)'** with the second one.

I would suggest using `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` because 1) That is what autocomplete suggests, and 2) All segues will go through there, not just unwinding ones. So it makes sense for the parameter to be called `segue`.

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify there is no difference and no benefit of choosing either one?

Comment: Thanks once again. I will change my code to that. :-)